# Delete file in folder and mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to delete file in mySQL table and folder simultaneously. So far, I can only delete the file in mysql table but the the same file still exist in the folder.

This is the delete script that I use.

```
<?php

include "../php/conn.php";

$query = " DELETE FROM fail WHERE id_f = ? ";

if($statement = $conn->prepare($query)){

    $statement->bind_param("i", $_GET['id_f']);

    if($statement->execute()){

    $statement->close();

    echo '<script>window.alert("Fail berjaya dihapuskan.");
    window.location=("../pensyarah/files.php");</script>';
        }

    else {

    echo '<script>window.alert("Gagal menghapus fail. Sila cuba lagi.");
    window.location=("../pensyarah/files.php");</script>';
        }
}

else {
    echo '<script>window.alert("Gagal menghapus fail. Sila cuba lagi.");
    window.location=("../pensyarah/files.php");</script>';
        }
    ?>
```

I'm trying to implement the PHP unlink , but i dont know how and where to punt the unlink in the script above. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: After the `if($statement->execute()){`I'd guess, that should be a successful delete from db, no? `Fail berjaya dihapuskan` sounds like an error.

Comment: Did you populate `$row` already? Once the `delete` executes you have no record. Oh, so `fail` == `file`, learn something everyday.

Comment: So, i should insert the `unlink("../php/$row['file]");` right afther the `if($statement->execute()){` ? Btw, Fail berjaya dihapuskan = File is deleted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try it this way....

```
$source = your_local_path_to_the_file; //c:\test\123.xls
unlink($source);  //try to delete it first

if (file_exists($source) {
   //raise error message, failed deleting
}else{
   //do your code in here to delete from mysql
}
```

Comment: Why not just `if` the `unlink`? This also doesn't tell the user where to put the delete.

Comment: where should i add this ? under the `$query` ? sorry, im still new with php

Comment: Tried your suggestion. It gives me this two errors. 

`Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\kkgri\php\padam_file.php on line 5`
and 
`Warning: unlink(../uploads/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\kkgri\php\padam_file.php on line 6`

Comment: you must change the ownership of the folder php and set the proper access rights.
what tools u use? php in linux/windows? shared hosting?